# Regarding Symfony 4 ChoiceType

Tags: symfony

I create the form with Symfony Form ChoiceType but there is one issue, for example i have a array like this

```
array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female')
```

I want key as key but Symfony Form Choice Type get key as value and value as key in dropdown

```
 <option value="Male">M</option>
 <option value="Female">F</option>
```

but i don't want like this, i want output like following :-

```
 <option value="M">Male</option>
 <option value="F">Female</option>
```

Sorry for my english

Comment: You may want to use `array_flip()`?

Comment: Is there any another option in Symfony without `array_flip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony `ChoiceType` uses the array key as the option name and the array value as the option value, there's no way around it if you wish to keep using the built in `ChoiceType`.

You will need to `array_flip` the original array before using it in the form type.